# Windows/Ubuntu Dual Machine -- how to increase Windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I currently have a dual machine with Windows 10/Ubuntu with Windows being my primary OS. I have seen a lot about increasing the Ubuntu partition, but I actually want to increase my Windows partition. How can I go about doing this? I have a working dual-boot machine and I want to make sure that I don't mess that up. I will definitely backup my data, but would prefer a data-loss route.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Post this from Ubuntu: `sudo parted -l` Then we can make better suggestions. Generally use Linux tools for Linux & Windows tools for Windows. Or use gparted from live installer to shrink or edit Linux partitions & Windows to modify Windows partitions. If BIOS/MBR, back up partition table also, Windows is known to delete Linux logical partition in partition table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running both **Windows** and **Linux** and you want to increase your Windows partition, by resizing your Ubuntu partition you could use the program [gparted](https://gparted.org/download.php) to make this change.

Here is the most up to date download for the [gparted-live-1.0.0-1-amd64.iso](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-1.1.0-1-amd64.iso).

The best way to use GParted is from Live media, such as GParted Live burned to a CD or written to a USB flash drive.

When your computer is booted from the hard drive, the operating system has access to the partitions.

To prevent this access and hence enable all supported partition editing actions, boot your computer using GParted Live removable media.

Here is a link for the [Gparted Live Manual](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual)

Here is the link to the help manual section on [Advanced Partition Actions](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-advanced-partition-actions) that explains in detail how to perform the resizing of partitions.

[image: Advanced-Partition-Actions]

When you have finished resizing your Ubuntu partition and prior to you making any changes to your Windows OS, you should create a [Recovery Drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852) in the event something goes wrong. This way you will be able to restore your Windows Operating System.
It's also a good idea to [back up your files](https://support.microsoft.com/help/17143) frequently do to the fact that the recovery drive isn't a system image. It doesn't contain your *personal files*, *settings*, or *programs*.

Here are a few guides to various recovery options.

- For Windows 7, see [Create a system repair disc](https://support.microsoft.com/help/17423).
- For Windows 8.1, see [Create a USB recovery drive](https://support.microsoft.com/help/17422).
- For Windows 10, see [Recovery options in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/help/12415).

If you're running: **WINDOWS 10**

To create a partition from unpartitioned space follow these steps:

1. Press the **Win + R** keys on your keyboard to open the Run dialog box, enter the command **diskmgmt.msc**, and then press **Enter** or **OK**
2. Select the disk from which you want to make a partition
3. Right-click the Un-partitioned space in the bottom pane and select **New Simple Volume**
4. Enter the size and click next and you are done.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: That i only half the truth, you really need to move avay the Linux partitions first.  Or have MS WIndows 10 support for different Linux file systems now?
So first resize the Linux partition, making it smaller.  Then make the MS Windows partition larger.  Make space FIRST, THEN use that new space.

Comment: @Anders that's correct, I was too focused on explaining how to resize the Windows partition that I completely forgot the first step. I will edit my answer. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: He was asking for reduce the size for the Linux partition, not remove it.  :-)

Comment: @Anders once again thanks for the tip. I corrected the issue, hopefully, this will answer their question satisfactorily.